# Thread Local Storage, is thread_local keyword a must?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, thread-local-storage

I'm trying to understand this concept.

Is the keyword `thread_local` or `__declspec(thread)` a must?

In the [Using Thread Local Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/using-thread-local-storage) on MSDN, why is the variable `dwTlsIndex` not decorated with `thread_local` or `__declspec(thread)`?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for TlsAlloc()?

Comment: You're confusing language features with Windows SDK features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dwTlsIndex` itself is not stored in any thread-local memory, that is why it is not marked as `thread_local` or `__declspec(thread)`.

The purpose of those keywords is to declare a *separate copy* of a given variable within each running thread.  `dwTlsIndex` is not meant to be copied that way.  It is a global variable initialized 1 time at program startup, via [`TlsAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-tlsalloc), and then shared equally by all running threads.  So it *can't* itself be stored in thread-local memory.

Each thread has its own local array of thread-local memory slots.  `dwTlsIndex` specifies the index of a given slot (variable) within those arrays.  The index of a given variable stored in thread-local memory is the same for all threads.  By sharing `dwTlsIndex` globally, all threads know which slot to access for that variable.

Read Microsoft's documentation for more details about how [Thread Local Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-local-storage) actually works.  You are focusing on a particular code example and not paying attention to the larger picture.